# Security warning: Website's certificate cannot be verified while running JWS application

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, signing, jar-signing

I am trying to run a JWS application. I have signed all the .jar files and placed them in the document root directory. The signing was done by a Verisign certificate using a .pfx file.
However, I still get a Security warning that says:
*"The website's certificate cannot be verified. Do you want to continue?"*
Name : IP address of the system hosting it
Publisher : UNKNOWN

When I accept it though, I get *Security Information* pop-up that I am expecting:
*"The application's digital signature has been verified. Do you want to run the application?"*

Why is it then that I get the Security warning pop-up window first? Should the certificate(.cer file) be placed else where apart from the Document Root directory?

Comment: *"I still get a Security warning that says:"* I don't think that is a Java Plug-in dialog.  Upload a clipped screen shot of it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The pop-up Window 'Warning-Security']

[image: Certificate]

When I clicked on more information, I saw the certificate details which was not the same with which I signed it.